# How do I efficiently search for a specific sequence in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

I'm looking through large arrays for particular sequences and I feel like I'm approaching the problem using brute force rather than computer **science**.

Currently I'm looking sequentially down the large array for the first item in the search sequence, then checking each item after that until a failure or a complete match. This provides 100% accuracy but it's not very fast with large arrays.

I was never a computer science student so I missed out on many algorithm classes that plenty of people around here probably had. Is there a better way to search for sequences in arrays? I'm not necessarily interested in perfect accuracy if it makes a difference.

Comment: Are the arrays in some sort of sorted order? What are you looking for in the arrays?  Sequentially is the best you can do for an unsorted array but if it is sorted we can do much better.

Comment: @Jordan It's not sortable data. Assume arbitrary order.

Comment: I always liked the KMP algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore_string_search_algorithm)? It's fairly simple and straightforward, and can increase the practical speed quite a lot, especially if your target sequence is fairly long. It's meant for searching for strings, but that's just a particular type of array of course.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand this won't reduce the need to sequentially transverse the array.  This will reduce the number of checks on an element to discard it or not.  It's a useful optimization but ultimately the OP will need to do a sequential search of the array due to the fact that it is unsorted.  Just clarifying.

Comment: Jordan, absolutely, it's a constant factor increase only. But if the target sequence is long it can still mean a large improvement in practice; a five time improvement or something on running time is nothing to sneeze at. As you say below, as long as he can't structure his data there's not much else to do.

Comment: Yes I agree, which is why I +1'ed you.  I just more wanted to clarify for the OP since he stated he didn't have a CS background exactly what benefit was being provided and what benefit he couldn't receive due to the nature of his problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way to search the array itself for candidates for matches.  If you have no order you cannot discard candidates as a match or not without considering them.

That being said you can optimize candidate acceptance or rejection utilizing the method suggested by Janne.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search for many patterns in the same sequence you can use [suffix arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)

If you have to search for one pattern then you can improve a little over brute force with Boyer-Moore or Knuth-Morris-Pratt